# Не могу спарсить строчку кода

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Не могу спарсить строчку кода. Нужно вывести(print) csrftokenw. Вот код сайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


session = requests.Session()

headers = {   
    'User-Agent': 'user-agent',
    'Cookie': '', 
    'Referer': 'https://www.mos.ru/'
     }

auth_url = 'https://login.mos.ru/sps/login/methods/password'
auth_req = session.get(auth_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
```

Comment: Никогда не используйте фотографии с кодом в вопросах, напишите сайт, который надо спарсить. и укажите ТЕКСТОМ ту часть, которую не получается спарсить. что у вас конкретно не получилось спарсить? добавьте минимальный пример, который не работает

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Начал отвечать на ваш другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183591), думаю, зря удалили, он был лучше :)

Получилось следующее (но я бы лучше через [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) работал с сайтом):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'

post_url = 'https://www.mos.ru/'
rs = session.get(post_url)
print("mos.ru status:", rs.status_code)

auth_url = 'https://www.mos.ru/api/acs/v1/login?back_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mos.ru%2F'
rs = session.get(auth_url)
print("login.mos.ru status:", rs.status_code)

root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

csrf_token = root.select_one('meta[name=csrf-token-value]')
print(csrf_token['content'])
# 16390112a86ceaae4559cac6c9e23b43ffaf99aecbc54ed84fcb0aa0af43ff03e29a522066398f0f
```

---

**PS.** `csrf токен` вытащил из тега `meta`, т.к. его не было в `input`. Похоже, туда значение перемещается через js

Comment: Спасибо огромное (Большое сердечко))

Comment: @Ilyshkadwaushka, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)